# Windows 7 32 Bit (on MacBook) Suddenly lost 1.5 G of RAM usable out of 4

Tags: windows-7, memory, macbook, nvidia-graphics-card, 32-bit

I have a MacBook Pro running Windows 7 32 Bit (under BootCamp).  It is a 4G machine, and has happily been running for 2 years with 3.5 or so usable RAM.  I started noticing the fan and hard drive working harder the last couple days, and today noticed that the usable RAM is now only 2.1G.

I looked at the Resources by Connection memory map in Device Manager, and see that 1.8 GB is being assigned to the GForce 330M card (address 90000000-FEAFFFFF).  I can only assume that this was not true before, and was, at the very least, substantially less, since I had 3.5 available.

My question is, how can I tell the GForce to stick to a smaller memory footprint?  Since I am on a MacBook, I don't think there is any way to disable/restrict it in the "BIOS", as recommended on some sites.  Obviously something was able to enable it to request more RAM.  (It may have happened after I got a message from windows last week asking if I wanted to disable Aero because I was getting low on memory -- I was running a lot of Visual Studios at once -- and I said yes, then finished what I was doing and rebooted.  But I am not sure if that was when it changed.)

Comment: What do you mean when you say the usable RAM?  How are you getting that figure?

Comment: Control Panel/System.  Under Installed memory (RAM) it says, "4.00 GB (2.18 GB Usable)".  I know _why_ it is that low (graphics card reserved memory), but not how it suddenly changed, or how I can change it back.

Answer (score 0):

Install the 64Bit Windows 7 or use a [PAE Patch](http://wj32.org/wp/2012/12/26/pae-patch-updated-for-windows-8/) with [implements this hack.](http://www.geoffchappell.com/viewer.htm?doc=notes/windows/license/memory.htm)

Comment: Thanks.  I am not quite ready to patch my OS.  My question was more related to getting it back to the state that it was in last week.

Comment: use system restore? Maybe an update (which patches the kernel) changed it.